# Google Cloud TTS API for M1 Mac

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, apple-m1

If I run Google TTS API [Python sample code](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries?hl=ko#using_the_client_library) in M1 mac, below error message shown. Can I use Google Cloud TTS API in M1 mac or not?

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PyCharm, this can be solved by following the [steps here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46290/Allow-running-Python-under-Rosetta-2-in-PyCharm-for-Apple-Silico). In case that link breaks, here are the instructions:

---

- Assuming a project `test_pkg_install_m1` with `venv` virtual environment inside
- Create `pythonM1` file inside `test_pkg_install_m1/venv/bin` with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
mydir=${0:a:h}
/usr/bin/arch -x86_64 $mydir/python "$@"
```

- Make the file executable with `chmod +x pythonM1`
- Add new interpreter in Preferences -> Project ... -> Project Interpreter targeting `pythonM1` as executable

Now all Python processes running by PyCharm will be executed with `arch -x86_64` including package installation.